# Store several values in cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

Im learning about cookies by trying to make a webshop cart.

All the products in the shop have a button that makes a cookie with a value like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Set a Cookie" onClick="setCookie('myCookie','it is crunchy', exp)">
```

I also have a button that prints the value (it is crunchy) to a textbox (shoppinglist).

Now, I would like the cookie to be able to store several values (items from the shop).

Here´s the code: (copied from a tutorial online):

```
function setCookie(name, value, expires) {
document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/" + ((expires == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString());
} 


var exp = new Date();     //set new date object
exp.setTime(exp.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30));     //set it 30 days ahead 


function getCookie (name) {
    var dc = document.cookie;
    var cname = name + "=";

    if (dc.length > 0) {
      begin = dc.indexOf(cname);
      if (begin != -1) {
        begin += cname.length;
        end = dc.indexOf(";", begin);
        if (end == -1) end = dc.length;
        return unescape(dc.substring(begin, end));
        }
      }
     return null;
}
```

I should add that i also have another button that adds the cookie-value to a textbox, like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Get Cookie Value" onClick="this.form.tf.value = getCookie('myCookie')">
```

Comment: I am (a) curious to know what a "crunchy" value is, particularly in relation to cookies, and (b) inclined to think you should look into `localStorage` for this kind of purpose.

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, just use JSON.

Comment: @lonesomeday his `<input>` sample was munged :)

Comment: The crunchy part is just an example. The real values are the names of the products in the shop which are stored in the cookie.

Comment: SLaks,im sure there are better ways but i really like to learn this. Thanks. 
Could I maybe create a var that saves all values after clicking...i dunno..

Comment: Is there a way to store the items in an array maybe?

Comment: [please check my code and correct it][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913977/cookie-is-not-storing-the-current-value-please-see-my-code